# Trigger filter only on click

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a list of data, this data is filtered by a dropdown menu.

The problem is, i want the filtering to be triggered only on a button click, not on the dropdown change.

```
<select ng-model="annee"  ng-options="annee.titre for annee in annees track by annee.id">

</select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filtrer">
<ul>

  <li ng-repeat="x in accueils | filter:annee" > 
    {{x.titre}}
    <div  ng-bind-html="x.description  | to_trusted"></div> 
    {{x.date}}
    {{x.cout}} $
    {{x.participants}} participants

  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a working example :

http://plnkr.co/edit/MbfrhdKfbTObybsQvxrR?p=preview

I want the filter to be triggered on clicking on the "filter" button

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your filter code here doesn't match your Plunker; it's `filter:{annee:annee.id}` in the Plunker.

You want to decouple the `ng-repeat` from the `ng-model`. One way to do this is to filter based on a new property and update that property only when the Filter button is clicked.

In your HTML:

- Add a `<form>` element and set `ng-submit` to call `submit()` when the Filter button is pressed:

  ```
  <form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl" ng-submit="submit()">
  ```
- Change the `ng-repeat` filter to use a new property instead of the property used by the `<select>` element's `ng-model`:

  ```
  <li ng-repeat="x in accueils | filter:{annee:currentAnnee.id}">
  ```

In your controller:

- Create the new property initialized with an invalid id:

  ```
  $scope.currentAnnee = {
      "id": 0
  };
  ```
- Create a `submit()` function that sets the new property from the `<select>` element's `ng-model`:

  ```
  $scope.submit = function() {
      $scope.currentAnnee = $scope.annee;
  };
  ```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CtxD0lEpUwqfWKAZQyUL?p=preview) for a complete example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the only change i made is to but the <form only around the <select> and <input. It works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @msmolens, there were some differences in your plunker and the code you posted here. Secondly, the two arrays that you have used, have nothing in common so for demonstration purposes i have changed the structure of the second array that will be used as filter.

To start with, decouple your Array filter from the model value of the select drop down.

```
    <select ng-model="annee"  ng-options="annee.date for annee in annees track by annee.id">
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filtrer" ng-click="filter()">

    <ul>

          <li ng-repeat="x in accueils | filter:filterExpr" > 
            {{x.titre}}
            <div  ng-bind-html="x.description  | to_trusted"></div> 
            {{x.date}}
            {{x.cout}} $
            {{x.participants}} participants

          </li>
    </ul>
```

As visible in the code, we have a model variable for the filter expression in the ng-repeat.

We then initialize the filter expression with a blank value.

```
    $scope.filterExpr = {"date" : ''};
```

There after, you just need to capture ng-click of the filter button and modify the variable being used as a filter.

```
    $scope.filter = function() {
      $scope.filterExpr = {"date" : $scope.annee.date};
    };
```

You can find the updated plunker [here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/VPwbCK02RAEQJ9ukSRRi?p=preview)